# JPA and JSF Datatable Optimization

Tags: jsf, optimization, jpa, datatable

I need to display a large table with about 1300 roles at one time. (I know I should use a data scroll but my users want to see the whole table at one time.) The table displays 4 columns. Two of those columns are from the object but the other two are from referenced objects in the original object. I need to find the best/efficient way to do this. I currently have this working but when I reload the table it give an out of memory error. I think that it's caused by the large amount of redundant data in memory.

1. Create a view object that the repository will fill in only the needed fields.
2. Any other suggestions.

Here are the objects:

```
    public class Database extends EntityObject {
      private Long id;
      private String name;
      private String connectionString;
      private String username; 
      private String password;
      private String description;

      // getter and setters omitted
    }

    public class Application extends EntityObject {
      private Long id;
      private String name;
      private String fullName = "";
      private String description;
      private Database database;
      private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>(0);

      // getter and setters omitted
    }

    public class Role extends EntityObject {
      private Long id;
      private String name;
      private String nameOnDatabase;
      private Application application;

      // getter and setters omitted
    }
```

What I need displayed from the list of Roles is:

role.id, role.name, role.application.name, role.application.database.name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To optimize wisely, define what are you going to do with data, view or/and edit. Here are some **common scenarios**:

1. <del>[Retrieval using lazy fetch type](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/retrieve#Retrieval_by_Eager_Fetch_). 
   Mark your roles in application with FetchType.LAZY annotation.</del>
2. [Retrieval using multiselect query](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select#Multiple_SELECT_Expressions_). Create your custom class (like DTO) and populate it with data from the database using multiselect query. (Similar to VIEW mapped as Entity)

There are also **other possibilities**, such as [Shared (L2) Entity Cache](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/cache) or [Retrieval by Refresh](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/retrieve#Retrieval_by_Refresh_).

**See if you are using EntityManager correctly** reading [Am I supposed to call EntityManager.clear() often to avoid memory leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243554/am-i-supposed-to-call-entitymanager-clear-often-to-avoid-memory-leaks).

Comment: Why would the OP want lazy loading? The OP's loading `Role`, `Application` and `Database`.

Comment: Retrieved Role will load Application, which will load List<Role> eagerly. Since you are retrieving all roles from database, I am not sure if hibernate will automatically look for already retrieved roles in its persistence context.

Comment: collections are fetched lazy by default to my knowledge.

Comment: @siebz0r yep, sorry, my bad. Then other options are still out there.