# HibernateTemplate .find() is reusing an old object

Tags: hibernate, object, find

In my code, same query with same parameters is getting executed twice in a loop during a short period of time using HibernateTemplate.find(). What is happening is, the address of the list returned by both the executions is the same. Why is Hibernate reusing an old object?

Comment: Reusing the old object is faster.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are First and Second Level caching in Hibernate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337072/what-are-first-and-second-level-caching-in-hibernate)

Comment: Hibernate caches previous results. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39022586/do-jpa-hibernate-load-data-which-changes-asynchronously-in-db/39026509#39026509 for more details.